# Need to understand the MDX query

Tags: mdx

```
 SELECT 
 { [Measures].[Net] } ON COLUMNS
 , NON EMPTY 
 { ([Bill To].[Customer Name].[Customer Name].ALLMEMBERS 
 * [Bill To].[Account Type].[Account Type].ALLMEMBERS 
 * [Reporting Date].[Fiscal Period].[Fiscal Period].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 
 ON ROWS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@EmployeeDimEmployeeManagerCode ) )  ON COLUMNS 
         FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@BillToDimCustAccountType ) ) ON COLUMNS 
         FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@GeneralLedgerDimGLBusinessUnit ) ) ON COLUMNS 
         FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@CompanyDimCompanyName ) ) ON COLUMNS 
         FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromCalendarDateDimMonth ) : STRTOMEMBER(@FromCalendarDateDimMonth ).LAG(11) ) ON COLUMNS 
         FROM [Revenue])))))  WHERE ( IIF( STRTOSET(@CompanyDimCompanyName, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
 , STRTOSET(@CompanyDimCompanyName, CONSTRAINED)
 , [Company].[Company].currentmember )
 , IIF( STRTOSET(@GeneralLedgerDimGLBusinessUnit, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
 , STRTOSET(@GeneralLedgerDimGLBusinessUnit, CONSTRAINED)
 , [Product].[GL Business Unit].currentmember )
 , IIF( STRTOSET(@EmployeeDimEmployeeManagerCode, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
 , STRTOSET(@EmployeeDimEmployeeManagerCode, CONSTRAINED)
 , [Order Primary Sales Assignment].[Order Primary Sales Assignment Manager Name].currentmember ) ) 
 CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE
 , FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

I am just a rookie MDX developer. In the query above(Written by somebody else) i didn't understand the   'from'  part. Why are we putting strtoset parameters in columns and what are we pulling from Revenue cube ???

Answer (score 0):

This query contains [subselects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487138.aspx); this feature isused to filter the query.

All the variables like `@EmployeeDimEmployeeManagerCode` will be replaced before executing the query. The [StrToSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144782.aspx) function is used to reduce the risk of injection attacks.